# How to disable embedded tomcat server while enabling actuator endpoint on a different tomcat instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've tried to add

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
management:
  server:
    port: 8081
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

But with that `none` property tomcat server with actuator endpoint doesn't get started

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That is  totally unclear to me

Comment: @M.Deinum you see I have a grpc server running on 9090, and I don't need redundant tomcat server running

Comment: Do you start that server through Spring Boot or yourself? Please add some more information to your question, like configuration, etc.

Comment: I'm using `grpc-spring-boot-starter` to start the server so yeah with spring boot

Comment: Then it won't start an additional tomcat, unless you specified that it should start an explicit management server.

Comment: Yeah, sorry should've added management properties

Comment: Remove the `management.server.port`, as you don't want an additional connector but rather use the same one. Also it doesn't start another tomcat instance it adds an additional connector to the existing one.

Comment: That's a very reasonable statement) Some other microservices use 8081 port, but good luck them with keeping actuator on 8081) Thanks @M.Deinum